# Canonical Rewrite for subpages not working by using rewrite rules in web.config

Tags: .net, azure, iis-7, url-rewriting, canonical-link

We have a simple HTML asp.net website hosted on Azure, we are facing a redirection issue when we copy paste the sub-page URL(without WWW) in the browser. 
Example : www.example.com/subpage.aspx works fine, but on copy pasting example.com/subpage.aspx it redirects to www.example.comsubpage.aspx/ (Frankly dunno where & how it is happening)

Following code was written in the web.config file in live, (except for the exact domain name)

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url=".*" />
               <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                 <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
     </rewrite>
```

Am new to this project, so any guidance on where should I start my investigation or where should I give the fix would be very helpful.

Comment: <code> <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^eyeswidewhat\.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.eyeswidewhat.net/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite> </code>

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.eyeswidewhat.net/{R:1}" />
```

Also, set `stopProccessing` to `true`.